# Is the firefox hack O.K to use?

Tags: css

I have used this hack to make css changes needed for firefox.   It has worked, but when I validated the code I have the below error.  Can I use the code below, or is there a better way?

```
751     Sorry, the at-rule @-moz-document is not implemented.
798     Parse Error }

/*********************************
FIRE FOX HACK TO FIX ERRORS
***********************************/
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  #rectangle {
       width: 1030px;
        right: -100px;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any CSS at-rule that starts with `@-moz-` is a Gecko-engine-specific rule i.e. it is a Mozilla-specific extension, not a standard rule.

The `url-prefix` rule here applies the contained style rules to any page whose URL starts with it. When used with no URL argument like `@-moz-document url-prefix()` it applies to ALL pages. That's effectively a CSS hack used to only target Gecko (Mozilla Firefox). All other browsers will ignore the styles.

Hence, you can perfectly use `@-moz-` styles to target only the Firefox browser.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions) for a list of other Mozilla-specific extensions.

See [here](https://github.com/stylish-userstyles/stylish/wiki/Valid-@-moz-document-rules) for valid `@moz document` rules.